# Create Directory in HTTPS Website

Tags: powershell

I upload files to a SharePoint website using this:

```
$sourcefile = "Reportdate.htm"
$sourceFilePath = "D:\$sourcefile"
$siteAddress = "https://Sharepoint.mysite.com/Reports"
$urlDest = "{0}/{1}" -f ($siteAddress, $sourceFile)
$webClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$WebClient.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials
$webClient.UploadFile($urlDest, "PUT", $sourceFilePath)
```

I would like to organise the uploaded files in the a new directory by date, I cant find a way to automatically create the new folder.

Searching around Google etc., shows how to do it via FTP, but that's not available. Installing the SharePoint snap-in is not preferable, if I can automatically create the folder using another method.

Comment: AFAIK It's not possible to create folders using PUT. It needs to be done on the server using sharepoint API, ftp, PowerShell remoting, creating a webservice you can call +++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this website that has the answer:

http://jleland.blogspot.com/2010/01/create-directories-and-upload-files-to.html

```
$url = "https://Sharepoint.mysite.com/Reports/Reports/$date"
$req = [System.Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create($url)
$req.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials
$req.Method = "MKCOL"
$res = $req.GetResponse()
```

So my final script checks if the new directory exists and if not creates it

```
$url = "https://Sharepoint.mysite.com/Reports/Reports/$date"
$check = ((wget $url -UseDefaultCredentials -ea 0).statuscode)
If  ($check -ne "200") {
$req = [System.Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create($url)
$req.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials
$req.Method = "MKCOL"
$req.GetResponse()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use MkCol with the simpler `Invoke-WebRequest`:

```bsh
 Invoke-WebRequest `
    -Uri $url `
    -Credential $cred `
    -CustomMethod 'MkCol' 
    # -SkipCertificateCheck # at your own risk, only on PS>6
```